# Type error cannot set property of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am developing app using Nodejs and Mongodb and mongoose. user and Subscriptions are 2 mongoose schemas. I want to get each members expire date from subscriptions collection and include it with each of members object array. But it is not working.

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String
    },
    firstName: {
        type: String
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String
    },
    displayName: {
        type: String
    },

});

var SubscriptionSchema = new Schema({
    member_id: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
},
    renewal_date: {
        type: Date
    },
    expire_date: {
        type: Date

    },

    amount: {
        type: String
    },
    paid_mode: {
        type: String
    },

});





exports.memberlist = function(req, res) {
    var expire='';

    user.find({}).lean().exec(function(err, collection) {



            var i;
            for(i=0;i<collection.length; i++)
            {



                 Subscriptions.find({'member_id':collection[i]._id}).lean().exec(function(err, subs){

                    if(subs.length > 0)
                        {

                            expire = subs[0].expire_date || '';
                        collection[i].expire_date = 'expire';

                        }


                   });


             }


        res.send(collection);

    });

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's control flow issue. You should use something like this

```
var async = require('async');

// ...

exports.memberlist = function(req, res) {
    var expire='';

    user.find({}).lean().exec(function(err, collection) {

        async.eachSeries(collection, function(item, cb){
            Subscriptions.find({'member_id':item._id}).lean().exec(function(err, subs){

                if(subs.length > 0)
                    {

                        expire = subs[0].expire_date || '';
                        collection[i].expire_date = 'expire';
                        cb()
                    }


               });


         }, function(){
             res.send(collection);
         });
    });
};
```

Read [here](http://book.mixu.net/node/ch7.html) about node control flow, and [here](https://github.com/caolan/async) about async module.